# PHP object nesting issue

Tags: php, reference, linked-list, nested

I am trying to create a circular linked list in php which is fairly simple as php objects are references. This means behavior of php objects should be similar to c++ pointers. Following is a simplified implementation of a linked list:

```
class Node{
    public $next;
}

$node1 = new Node();
$node2 = new Node();

$node1->next = $node2;
$node2->next = $node1;
```

After implementing this I realized crazy things start happening when you link your objects in a circular list. e.g. you get an error while comparing these objects using == operator:

```
if($node1 == $node2) //Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?
```

I found out correct way to compare these objects is to use strict comparison.

```
if($node1 === $node2) //Works fine
```

I think non-strict comparison tries to compare all attributes of object. In doing so it finds out that there is infinite nesting so it reports an error. But what I cannot figure out is why the following works:

```
if($node1->next == $node2) //Works fine with == rather than ===
```

**Conclusion:**

Always use identity operator (===) to compare objects - unless you want compare to return true for similar objects with different instances, but be aware of the nesting issue.

Comment: Using the === operator means it checks the type and value of the objects in question. == Does a lazy comparison. Here is the manual on comparison operators. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: but then why does if($node1->next == $node2) work? It should report nesting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know,
PHP compare two objects only by looking into their properties indefinitely until ends.

### if($node1 == $node2)

```
 $node1 == $node2?
 if $node1 -> next == $node2->next 
  if $node1->next(node2)->next == $node2->next(node1)->next 
    if $node1->next(node2)->next(node1)->next == $node2->next(node1)->next(node2)->next;
```

**Indefinitely...**

if an object has property, it will look into them if you compare two objects.

So, for why your strict comparison works because it will simply check whether the two objects are at the **same location in memory** and so it do not even look at the values of the properties.

### if($node1->next == $node2)

For why comparing **if($node1->next == $node2)** worked fine i guesses as below:
PHP compares for "address" first, if two objects going to be compared have the same address. PHP assumes they must be identical **as they resides in the same place**.

Like $node1 has an address of 1.
And $node2 has an address of 2.
$node2->next then have an address of 1.
**same address, PHP dont want look into properties now, because they resides in the same place.**

Also, for your reference. The compare result of "==" and "===" respectively on php.net
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

```
Two instances of the same class
o1 == o2 : TRUE
o1 != o2 : FALSE
o1 === o2 : FALSE
o1 !== o2 : TRUE

Two references to the same instance
o1 == o2 : TRUE
o1 != o2 : FALSE
o1 === o2 : TRUE
o1 !== o2 : FALSE

Instances of two different classes
o1 == o2 : FALSE
o1 != o2 : TRUE
o1 === o2 : FALSE
o1 !== o2 : TRUE
```

Comment: But in the latter case it works even with non-strict comparison.

Comment: I am sorry, but i cannot explain that :(. But seems that comparing against exactly the same address(ref) returns true anyway.
Like $node1 has an address of 1. $node2->next have an address of 1 too.
And PHP seems to think that exactly the same address, **why they will be different?**

Comment: This means that non-strict comparison (==) always compares reference of the object before comparing attributes and values.

Comment: Most likely, because experimentally outcome is that :) I think it is logical too for not start comparing if we are on the same address.

Comment: I expect it is comparing address first in the "==" case, if **if($node2 == $node2)** did not throw error, because they are the same piece in memory, thus the comparison is skipped and return true anyway.

Comment: This means that a non-strict comparison first uses strict comparison and then uses non-strict i.e. starts comparing attributes and values. that's weird.

Comment: Not quite. "==" is done after type juggling. "===" do not do any type conversion, and compare it directly and type-strict. Thus, it still make sense for before doing type juggling, check their address first for saving some cpu overheads.

Answer (score 1):

As you have concluded in php object comparison using "==" involves comparing attributes of the object and can become recursive

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are
>   compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if
>   they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the
>   same class.
>
> On the other hand, when using the identity operator (===), object
>   variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance
>   of the same class.

Now in the latter case it works because you are comparing node2 with node2.  For ex:

```
if($node2 == $node2)  //works since there it can conclude in 1 step both are same objects
```

while

```
if($node2->next == $node2) //will still have the recursion issue since it has to follow the links
```

Comment: But in the latter case (==) why doesn't it report nesting issue when comparing attributes because they are circularly linked? Or does it not compare attributes if both refer to same instance.

Comment: Ah I missed that in the initial answer, edited to answer that part, when you are comparing the same object to itself there is no recursion issue.

Comment: but how does non-strict comparison know that it is the same object?

Comment: so it is the same logic, while comparing objects in php, it has to make sure the attribute are same. In $node2 == $node2 comparions, it is easy to see the attributes are same since the attribute is pointing to the same object ($node1). In $node1 == $node2 case, it tries to make sure the attributes are same and tries to follow the pointers endlessly.

Comment: but in case of $node2 == $node2 if it tries to compare "all" attributes it would still get caught in recursion. How does it know where to stop comparing.

Comment: if the pointers are same then it doesn't have to follow the pointer since it is sure they are the same object.

Comment: Ok so this means that a non-strict comparison (==) uses strict comparison (===) when comparing attributes and values.

Comment: Nope I don't mean that, it will stop once it can resolve. for ex. if $node1->next = $node2->next = $node3. Then if ($node1 == $node2) will be fine. It doesn't have to follow links endlessly here